# How can I make my own posts community-wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I see many community wiki questions. How can I make my own question community wiki?

Comment: Related: [FAQ: What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Earn some more reps, and you will see community wiki check box on your posts

Comment: How much repo required for at. I have 940 now?

Comment: Hum, You should have one, for that case. You could try to edit/create a post and look at right button corner of the text box, and find the checkbox called `community wiki`

Comment: aah got it. I have a check box at below right for question/answer box. Never noticed that before. Thanks Mark..

Comment: ok, but please keep in mind that community wiki posts won't generate reps.

Comment: The reputation threshold is 15 for getting the community wiki check box.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?